# Polling large Data from the database

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009, biztalk-2010, biztalk2006r2

```
  I have written stored procedure to poll the data from the database in biztalk.but the datasize is very large its around 80MB...Due to which i am getting error.Does anyone knows what configuration do i need to change to poll that much big amount of data.
```

in the table EDI834_5010_2300Loop  i have around 35000 rows i need to chucnk the data depending upon this table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by big amount of data? Big blob fields or many rows? If latter is the reason - modify your procedure to return data in chunks and set PollWhileDataAvailable =  true in adapter.

In one of my current projects I use such procedure code to get data in chunks:

```
DECLARE @SubsetOfChanges TABLE (ChangeID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT INTO @SubsetOfChanges
SELECT TOP 100 ChangeID FROM bts_DatabaseChanges WHERE Processed = 0 AND TableName = 'Producer'

SELECT p.*, changes.Operation as operation, changes.RowKey AS original_id 
FROM (SELECT * FROM bts_DatabaseChanges WHERE ChangeID IN (SELECT * FROM @SubsetOfChanges)) AS changes
JOIN [region].[dbo].crm_clsProducer p ON changes.RowKey = p.producer_id  

UPDATE bts_DatabaseChanges
SET Processed = 1
WHERE ChangeID IN (SELECT * FROM @SubsetOfChanges)
```

bts_DatabaseChanges is a log-table for all modifications in the DB.

Comment: it means big numner of rows.............what to change in my procedure so that it will return data in chunks......

Comment: Thanks Dmitry.Let me try this way.

Comment: My Stored procedure is like above i was not able to make changes by using your sample.could you help me in that.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the WCF LOB Adapters for this? If so, check te MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the bindings on your send receive port to increase from the default 65000 bytes.